# Add UI component in fragments dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, dynamic, android-imageview

I have an activity and a fragment. Activity has a trigger event which adds an Imageview to fragment every time event is triggered. 
Now I wish to programmatically add image view on every event trigger and refresh the fragment UI.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use a recyclerview then?

Just use a recyclerview and whenever you get the trigger you can add that image dynamically.. or you can inflate image view directly on the parent view.. like: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ivLay,'your main layout',true);

ivLay.xml

Answer (score 1):

The fragment is just a container for your layout. Basically, you'd have to call `addView` on the `ViewGroup` layout that is hosted in the fragment. The `ViewGroup` could be a `LinearLayout` for instance. Link to documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

But as mentioned, you could use a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` and an adapter to accomplish this easier, as it would also save you from messing with `LayoutParams`, plus it would give you some performance improvements with the help of recycling.